# Define automapper profile when there are multiple levels of hierarchy

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I have got a JSON like this

```
{
   "assessments":[
      {

         "deliveryTeamName":"Reporting Team",
         "programIncrementId":"125",
         "programIncrementName":"1",
         "sprintId":"558",
         "sprintName":"1",
         "isDeleted":false,
         "created":"2018-04-24T08:39:19",
         "createdBy":"Vijaykumar",
         "objectives":[
            {
               "objectiveId":"118",
               "objectiveTitle":"Position level data (Stretch)"
            },
            {
               "objectiveId":"261",
               "objectiveTitle":"Configure for Internal users"
            }
         ],
         "answers":[
            {
               "questionId":"35",
               "questionTitle":"Question 2"
            },
            {
               "questionId":"36",
               "questionTitle":"Question 2a"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And here is the class I have created for deserialization.

```
public class listOfSelfAssessments
{
    public class selfAssessments
    {
        public List<assessments> assessments { get; set; }

    }
    public class assessments
    {
        public string deliveryTeamName { get; set; }
        public string programIncrementId { get; set; }
        public string programIncrementName { get; set; }
        public string sprintId { get; set; }
        public string sprintName { get; set; }

        public string created { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public List<objectives> objectives { get; set; }
        public List<answers> answers { get; set; }

    }

    public class objectives
    {
        public string objectiveId { get; set; }
        public string objectiveTitle { get; set; }

    }
    public class answers
    {
        public string questionId { get; set; }
        public string questionTitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Everything working fine till deserialization

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // your datetime format
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format };
listOfSelfAssessments.selfAssessments results = new listOfSelfAssessments.selfAssessments();
results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<listOfSelfAssessments.selfAssessments>(responseBody);
```

But the problem comes here when my final table to which I want to write this data looks like this

```
team_name       Type        pi_id      pi_name     sprint_id      Sprint_Name   Type_Id    Title
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reporting Team  Objective    125         1             558          1             118       Position Level Data
Reporting Team  Objective    125         1             558          1             261       Configure for internal users
Reporting Team  Question    125         1             558          1             35       Question 2
Reporting Team  Question    125         1             558          1             36       Question 2a
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the tables model class

```
public partial class BmtSelfassessmentResponse
{

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string Pi { get; set; }
    public string Sprint { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
}
```

I have no idea how to create the Automapper profile for this json and the table's model class

Please share an idea. Or relying automapper in this such complicated hierarchy is not a good way?

Comment: Automapper could be bent to flatten the data, though it was not intended for this. But it's maybe better to do it by hand, with a little help of LINQ.

Comment: Post The table's model class too

Comment: @Dialecticus It would be great if you share some hint how to deal it with linq or any arrow functions

Comment: Try googling for "automapper one to many".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Dialecticus about the linq way through which I was able to implement it without much effort. Just posting this for someone who got similar requirement

```
var objectives = (from a in results.assessments
                  from o in a.objectives
                  select new BmtSelfassessmentResponse { Art = a.agileReleaseTrainName, Team = a.deliveryTeamName, Active = true, ResponseV = (int.TryParse(o.completePercentage, out int p) ? (Convert.ToDecimal(o.completePercentage) / 100) : null), Type = "Objective" });
var answers = (from a in results.assessments
               from q in a.answers
               select new BmtSelfassessmentResponse { Art = a.agileReleaseTrainName, Team = a.deliveryTeamName, Active = true, ResponseT = q.answer,Type="Question" });
    
List<BmtSelfassessmentResponse> SA = objectives.Concat(answers).ToList<BmtSelfassessmentResponse>();
```